# Language codes reference

Tags: localization

Can someone please give me the official reference to the language (country/region) codes. I'm  finding different codes for the same language (es_ES, esp_ESP, etc.) and I can't figure out which one is the right one.

Comment: What kind of standard you use ? There are a lot of ways to define languages check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_languages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several different standards specifying language codes, including ISO-639 with its sub-standards 1-3 and IETF language tags, which describe more of a system of possible codes than the codes themselves.

Which standard is "the right" standard depends on your use case and context. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_codes.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the languages naming coding has different standards, using different number of letters. You might have to chose which standard to use and maybe detect which standard the data source you have is using.

This is a starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes

Answer (score 1):

you can find all the regions code in **documentation** [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

These codes are a combination of the specific language as well as the conuntry in which the language is used. So for instance means `es_ES` `spanish_Spain`. Another one would be `es_AR` which would mean `spanish_Argentina`. For the language code there's the [Language Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1_language_matrix), as for the localisation part you could use the [ISO 3166-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2) country reference